# Invoke a function without assigning its result to a variable

Tags: javascript

The `map` function looks much better than a `for` loop:

```
var arr = ["Apple", "Orange"];
// map example
arr.map(function(item){ eat(item); });
// for example
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    eat(arr[i]);
}
```

And I would prefer a `map` over `for` but:

1. A function, which `map` becomes as an argument should have a return value to be reduces to an array which `map` should return. What impact has passing a viod function to a `map`, like in my example?
2. `map` returns an array. What happens if I don't assign it to a variable, like in my example?
3. Is there any void function like `map`?

Comment: What happened in that title? "assuaging" :)

Comment: 3.  [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A function, which map becomes as an argument should have a return value to be reduces to an array which map should return. What impact has passing a viod function to a map, like in my example?

The value returned by a function without a return statement is `undefined`. Thus, if you pass a function that never returns anything to map, it will create a new array with length equal to your original array and each value being `undefined`.

> map returns an array. What happens if I don't assign it to a variable, like in my example?

An array is still created but it will be discarded immediately after creation and garbage collected shortly. This behavior might be optimized away by the JS engine!

> Is there any void function like map?

As everyone else pointed out, there is the `Array.prototype.forEach` function which iterates over the array (similarly to map) but doesn't create a new array or use the result of the callback associated to it in any way.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `.forEach()`.

You may find that browsing the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is a better way to accumulate this sort of information than asking questions. For now at least I hope this answer will assuage your suffering.

*edit* — as to question 1, it won't hurt anything. The `.map()` function will build an array full of `undefined` entries. (I think.)

For 2, it's also OK.  It is never a problem to ignore the return value of a function, at least as far as the runtime is concerned.

Comment: Nice answer for 3. point. But i cannot find any info for 1. and 2.

Comment: @speechkey ok I think I see what you're asking; I'll add to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**1. A function, which map becomes as an argument should have a return value to be reduces to an array which map should return. What impact has passing a viod function to a map, like in my example?**

```
var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
var mapped = numbers.map(function(){
    //do nothing
});
console.log(numbers);//[1, 4, 9]
console.log(mapped);//[undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

the initial array will remain as same and you will get an array with undefined array

**2 . map returns an array. What happens if I don't assign it to a variable, like in my 
example?**

*nothing* will happen, you loose the changed array.

**3.Is there any void function like map?**

All array methods doesnot modify the reference array , 
EG

```
Array.concat(value1[value2[value...]])
Array.every(function)
Array.filter(function)
Array.forEach(function)
Array.join(delimeter)
Array.indexOf(searchStr[, startIndex])
Array.lastIndexOf(searchStr[, startIndex])
Array.map(function) .... etc
```

but `Array.splice(), push, pop, shift, unshift,.. etc` will change

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice` does not change the array. The only methods that change the array are `splice`, `push`, `pop`, `shift`, `unshift`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [`forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
var arr = ["Apple", "Orange"];
arr.forEach(eat);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) array instance method.